# Learndash change user role after completing the course

Tags: user-roles

I am moving a site from a LearnPress LMS to the LearnDash LMS, and I need to move over a custom function that changes the user role when the user completes the course (there is only one course right now).  The user flow is the following:  New user registers -> they are assigned a pre-subscriber role (this code is working, see below).  Once the user completes the course, their user role changes from pre-subscriber to subscriber.

```
function cst_pre_creator_role() {
if ( get_option( 'pre_creator_role_version' ) < 1 ) {
    add_role( 'pre_subscriber', 'Pre Creator', array( 'read' => true, 'level_0' => true ) );
    update_option( 'pre_creator_role_version', 1 );
}}

add_action( 'user_register', 'cst_change_role', 10, 2 );
function cst_change_role($user_id, $userdata){
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user->set_role( 'pre_subscriber' );
}
```

The problem I am running into is how to link the Learndash function or functions to return the completion status as true or similar.  I am looking at learndash_course_completed / learndash_course_status.

Below is the code that was working with LearnPress.

```
add_action('wp_head', function(){

    if(is_user_logged_in()){
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            if ( in_array( 'pre_subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
                    $profile = LP_Profile::instance( $user->ID );
                    $Lpuser    = $profile->get_user();
                    $course_id      = 8217;
                    $course         = learn_press_get_course( $course_id );
                    $course_data    = $Lpuser->get_course_data( $course_id );
                    $course_results = $course_data->get_results( '' );
                    $status         = $course_results['status'];
                    $grade          = $course_data->get_graduation();
                    if($grade == "passed"){
                            // Remove role
                            $user->remove_role( 'pre_subscriber' );
                            // Add role
                            $user->add_role( 'subscriber' );
                    }
            }
    }
});
```

Any help with translating this LearnPress function into a LearnDash function would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Discussions of third party plugins are off topic. You may get better help on LearnDash support.

Comment: @Abhik.  Learndash does not provide any developer support.  Just basic user functionality.  That is why I posted this here.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed.  Here is the code:

```
add_action('wp_head', function(){

if(is_user_logged_in()){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'pre_subscriber', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
$passed = learndash_user_quiz_has_completed($user->ID, 8731, 8388);
        if($passed){
            // Remove role
            $user->remove_role( 'pre_subscriber' );
            // Add role
            $user->add_role( 'subscriber' );
        }
    }
}}
      );
```